# SyntaxError on static class property with Babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I am trying to create a component using ES2016 syntax as:

```
export default class {
  static defaultProps = {
    color: '#cc7f29',
  }
}
```

I believe `static defaultProps = {}` syntax is part of ES2016 so I loaded ES2016 preset into Babel. I have installed `babel-preset-es2016` already.

This gives error in compilation:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:22)

   8 | export default class extends React.Component {
   9 | 
> 10 |   static defaultProps = {
     |                       ^
  11 |     color: '#cc7f29',
  12 |     theme: 'light',
  13 |   }

BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:22)

   8 | export default class extends React.Component {
   9 | 
> 10 |   static defaultProps = {
     |                       ^
  11 |     color: '#cc7f29',
  12 |     theme: 'light',
  13 |   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you read the [tag:ecmascript-7] description, then you can see that public class fields are not part of that revision.

Answer (score 1):

Class properties are ECMAScript stage 2 proposal, so you need to include [stage 2 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/).

Using stage 0 preset works too, because it includes all previous stage presets.